# Puting $n$ balls in ordered bins

Tags: combinatorics

I have $n$ balls $\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ and $m$ bins $\{B_1,...,B_m\}$ how many ways there are to put the balls in the bins in such a way that the ball $i+1$ is in a bin greater or equal than the ball $i$?

For example with $n=2$ and $m=3$ we get the following solutions:
$(b_1,b_2)()()$; $(b_1)(b_2)()$; $(b_1)()(b_2)$;$()(b_1,b_2)()$; $()(b_1)(b_2)$ and $()()(b_1,b_2)$ thus $6$.

Comment: Try to look at it this way: We first place $m-1$ walls on $n+m-1$ spots. Then we lay the balls down in order on the spots that remain. This can be done in ${n+m-1\choose m-1} $ ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the order of the balls fixed (in the manner required, that is, increasing). Now just place spaces in between the balls. For $m$ bins, you need to place $m-1$ spaces. There are total $n+m-1$ objects ($n$ balls and $m-1$ bins) and you need to choose $m-1$ of those as spaces. Thus, the number of ways to do so is $\binom{n+m-1}{m-1}$.

As the order of the balls is fixed, you can simply use the formula to place $n$ identical balls in $m$ bins. And when you are done placing them, order the balls from left to right in increasing order.